# Arrange Chat Messages By Date

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, javascript-objects

I am working with Vue, but this is a general javascript question.
I make a call to an api to get cat messages for a chat UI. The initial call returns an array of objects where each object is a chat message object as below.

```
data: [
  0: {id: 1, created_at: "2022-05-20T15:12:40.000000Z", updated_at: "2022-05-20T17:18:03.000000Z",…}
  1: {id: 2, created_at: "2022-05-20T15:12:41.000000Z", updated_at: "2022-05-20T17:18:04.000000Z",…}
  2: {id: 3, created_at: "2022-05-20T15:12:41.000000Z", updated_at: "2022-05-20T17:18:04.000000Z",…}
  3: {id: 4, created_at: "2022-05-20T15:12:41.000000Z", updated_at: "2022-05-20T17:18:04.000000Z",…}
]
```

I initial wanted to format the message so they can be grouped by their dates in the chat window. This is the code I used to group them

`This is a computed property in vue`

```
    const formattedChats = computed(() => {
      let dateFormattedMessages = messages.value.map(message => {
        return {...message, updated_at: new Date(message.updated_at).toDateString(), created_at: new Date(message.created_at).toDateString()}
      })
      return dateFormattedMessages.reduce((total, currentValue) => {
        total[currentValue.updated_at] = total[currentValue.updated_at] || [];
        total[currentValue.updated_at].push(currentValue);
        return total;
      }, Object.create(null));
    })
```

The above will first take the each chat object an convert their `updated_at` and `created_at` to a date string and then group the array using the updated_at.
The result was as follows:

```
formattedChats = {
  Fri Jun 24 2022: [
    {...}, {...
  ]
  Fri May 20 2022:[
    {...}, {...
  ]
  Mon Jun 27 2022:Array[
    {...}, {...
  ]
  Sat May 21 2022:Array[
    {...}, {...
  ]
  Tue Jun 28 2022:Array[
    {...}, {...
  ]
}
```

If you notice, the problem I am facing is that the dates are not arranged in any order. it doesnt make sense to render it to the UI like this because the resulting chats with not be arranged by date.
This is how the UI should look[image: chat window sample]

Comment: Dates are sorted by alphabet, a wrong way to stringify them was used. It's not a good idea to use plain objects for lists, especially because the order of keys is not guaranteed if they are assigned in random order.  This is what arrays, maps and sets are for

Answer (score 0):

You need to use arrays (or a map) to keep the order sorted. I would use an array of arrays. First you need to sort the data on date (I used `updated_at`, which I made of type Date in the data array). Then iterate over the sorted array. See snippet below.

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    updated_at: new Date("2022-05-21T15:12:40.000000Z"),
    created_at: "2022-05-20T17:18:03.000000Z"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    updated_at: new Date("2022-05-20T15:12:41.000000Z"),
    created_at: "2022-05-20T17:18:04.000000Z"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    updated_at: new Date("2022-05-23T15:12:41.000000Z"),
    created_at: "2022-05-20T17:18:04.000000Z"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    updated_at: new Date("2022-05-21T15:12:41.000000Z"),
    created_at: "2022-05-20T17:18:04.000000Z"
  },
]

const sortedData = data.sort(
  (a, b) => Number(a.updated_at) - Number(b.updated_at),
);


let currentDay = sortedData[0].updated_at;

const stillCurrentDay = (dayOfMessage) => {
  return dayOfMessage.getFullYear() === currentDay.getFullYear() &&
    dayOfMessage.getMonth() === currentDay.getMonth() &&
    dayOfMessage.getDate() === currentDay.getDate()
}

let dayMessageArray = [];
const fullMessageArray = [];

const createMessagesArray = (messages) => {
  const newDay = {};
  newDay[currentDay.toISOString().split('T')[0]] = messages;
  fullMessageArray.push(newDay);
}

sortedData.forEach(message => {
  if (!stillCurrentDay(message.updated_at)) {
    createMessagesArray(dayMessageArray);
    currentDay = message.updated_at;
    dayMessageArray = [];
  }

  dayMessageArray.push(message);
});

createMessagesArray(dayMessageArray);

console.log(fullMessageArray);
```

Hope this helps. Perhaps there are easier ways, please let me know.